# Equation of a line maintaining equal ratio distance between two points.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Say I have two points. One at $A = (0, 0)$ and another at $B = (0, 10)$. I wish to derive an equation for a line that, for any point $P$ on the line, would equal a set ratio for the distance $P$ to $A$ and $P$ to $B$.

This is easy if the predetermined ratio for $A:B$ is $1:1$. I would create a line from $A$ to $B$, find its midpoint, then create an orthogonal line at the midpoint. Then at any $P$ on the line I know that the ratio distances from $P$ to $A$ and $B$ will be $1:1$.

But what if the ratio for $A:B$ is something like $11:18$?

This is for a positioning algorithm I am implementing - not for homework :)

EDIT: Note - If an exact formula is not possible, an approximation of the line out to $\pm 200$ from $A$ or $B$ is acceptable as values further from $A$ and $B$ will not be utilized anyway. A linear equation for the final result/approximation is ideal for speed in running multiple computations.

Comment: If the ratio isn't 1:1, the locus of points with that ratio of the distances is a circle, not a straight line.

Comment: I was thinking that the line would have to be curved and would probably even have a threshold to maintain the ratio, so a circle would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DanielFischer said, the locus is a circle if the ratio isn't $1:1$.  This is known as [Apollonius' Circle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius).

Comment: Great reference! Thank you. No matter how I tried searching Google for what I wanted, I could not seem to find a good reference. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)