# Calculating the Apollonius Circle

Tags: trigonometry, circles

This is a followup to a [question I asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596644/equation-of-a-line-maintaining-equal-ratio-distance-between-two-points).

I have looked for an example on Google and StackExchange, but I have yet to see a clear example of the formula to determine the equation of an [Apollonian Circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) given two points and a ratio.

For example, if I have points $A = (0, 0)$ and $B = (3, 1)$ and want to maintain a ratio of $11:13$ between them, how could I get the Apollonian Circle?

I am far from being good at interpreting condensed mathematical notation (which is why [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328836/apollonius-circle) did not help me), so a step-wise process would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done? What have you tried? Which step are you stuck at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a point $(x,y)$, we want to find those that satisfy

$$ 13 \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = 11 \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2}. $$

Square and expand, and convert it into an equation of the form

$$ (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2. $$

Comment: Awesome! That makes a lot of sense on scaling each side by my ratios. But, I need to extract h, k, and r in code, so expanding and processing that beast in code is daunting. Do you know of a short way, given your original expression, to extract those values? Much appreciated.

Comment: @EricOlson Just expand both side and compare coefficients.